# Swift character makes unsuccessful escape

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

The first print statement below works fine but not the second.  The second one generates the error `"Expected '}" in \u{...} escape sequence"`.  (They should (in theory) be the same,)

```
print("\u{F0A5}")
let generatedValue = "F0A5"
print("\u{\(generatedValue)}")
```

I've tried various formatting tricks without success.  How do I overcome this error to produce an escaped special character string on the fly?

Comment: Well spotted, those people.  It was hardly likely I was first to come across this problem but was unable to formulate a successful Google search.